# Python - How to compare two numpy arrays and output a third marking where each element is the same or different

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have two arrays such as

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

and

```
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
```

And I want to compare them and output a third array such as this

```
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Because this would tell me whether for each element in both arrays it was a 0 or a 1.

In the future I would also like to run other comparisons such as to see whether one element is a 1 in one array and a 0 in another, whether the particular element is missing from both ect.

Note: I describe an element as a 0 or 1 in the same position in both arrays - both arrays are the same size and a 1 means the element exists and a 0 marks that it does not exist.

Thanks.

Comment: If they were actual numpy arrays, `n1 == n2` would do it.

Comment: That just gives me True where the elements are the same and False where they are not but I need to count how many 0's and 1's there are after in the third array.

Comment: Your title is asking something completely different from your question body, which is in turn asking something different from your comment. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Not really, just different levels of info, the title length is not long enough to explain everyting

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it turns out that a simple '&' operator will do this without any complicated loops.

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Which _can_ also be spelt `np.bitwise_and(x, y)`, since you were struggling to find the name for it. But I'd stick with using the `x & y` operator for brevity.